# Requiring single module file to namespace multiple classes in multiple files

Tags: ruby, class, module

I am interested in defining multiple classes across multiple files that belong to the same module. Module CktCheck should have include the class Sdevv. Here is the code:

```
module CktCheck
  require 'Sdevv.rb'
end
```

In the Sdevv.rb file, I have:

```
class Sdevv
...
...
end
```

I want to instantiate an instance of class Sdevv, by using these lines

```
require("CktCheck.rb")
cktcheck_file = CktCheck::Sdevv.new("CktCheck.sdevv")
```

However, the following exception is raised:

```
./isBeginDevLine.rb:6:in `<main>': uninitialized constant CktCheck::Sdevv (NameError)`
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `include` instead of `require`?

Also, you could just open the module in the other file to have the class added:

```
# In Sdevv.rb:

module CktCheck
  class Sdevv
  ...
  ...
  end
end

# Then, when you need it:
require("CktCheck")
require("Sdevv")
```

Comment: Module works as expected. I guess I was thinking too much in Hardware description languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that having a  separate module file is good idea. Idea behind 'modules' is to

1. group similar things of same sort by keeping them in same 'namespace'(i.e module name)
2. avoid name collision when the 'name' that you used, happens to be used in other namespaces(*other modules*).

Its is fine to have 1 file per class and  define all your new classes in a same module by reopening the that module.

```
#In first_thing.rb
module SameThings
  class FirstThing
  ....
  end
end

#In second_thing.rb
module SameThings
  class SecondThing
  .....
  end
end

now where ever you need to use FirstThing or SecondThing  
require 'first_thing'   or 
require 'second_thing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Sdevv.rb`, you forgot to define class `Sdevv` inside the `CktCheck` module. Therefore, it is defined at the top-level.

You need to either reference it from the top-level simply as `Sdevv` instead of `CktCheck::Sdevv` or, if you want it to be defined inside the `CktCheck` module, then you, well, have to define it inside the `CktCheck` module:

```
module CktCheck
  class Sdevv
    # …
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand... I was told that require is like the load in Tcl, and that is simply continues to interpert w/o losing context.